# html boilerplate gap at top of webpage

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

I'm new to HTML5 boilerplate and trying to build a page.Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/deus/Dr38e/).

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="home">
            <div id="logoBox">
                <div id="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- logoBox ends -->
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HOME</li>
                        <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
                        <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
                        <li>ABOUT</li>
                        <li>CONTACT</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- home ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- Wrapper ends -->
```

CSS code:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    /* Firefox */
}
html, body {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /*border:1px solid #000000;*/
}
#wrapper {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*border:1px solid #FFFFFF;*/
    display : box;
    overflow:hidden; /*auto*/
}

@keyframes btnHvr {
    from {
        background-color:#8bca3c;
    }
    to {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes btnHvr
/*Safari and Chrome*/
 {
    from {
        background-color:#8bca3c;
    }
    to {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
}

#home {
    width:100%;    
    height:auto;
    background-color:#8bca3c;
    /*border:1px solid #000000;    <<-- This border removes the gap*/
}

#logoBox {
    /*border:1px solid #000000;*/
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:5em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}
#logo {
    height:8em;
    width:8em;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:8em;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color:#8bca3c;
    border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#logo:hover {
    color:#8bca3c;
    animation: btnHvr 1s;
    -webkit-animation:btnHvr 1s;
    /*Safari and Chrome*/
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
nav {
    margin:auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
Header nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:9.5em;
    height:auto;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom:0.4em;
    background-color : #8bca3c;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-right:-1px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    color:#FFFFFF;

    font-family:"Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;

    font-weight: bold;*/
}

header nav li:hover {
    color:#8bca3c;
    animation: btnHvr 1s;
    -webkit-animation:btnHvr 1s;
    /*Safari and Chrome*/
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
```

Why there is a gap at the top the webpage.

If I use the border for `#home` div, then the gap vanishes. 
I've tried every answer in stackoverflow and other resources,but the none of the solutions worked in case of my code.

Is there an alternate solution apart from using **border**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a big `margin-top` for the div `#logoBox`.

Just do this way, altering the **CSS**, it might work:

```css
#logoBox {margin-top: 0; padding-top: 5em;}
```

---

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr38e/1/

Comment: Why the gap disappears , when using border for #home div ?

Comment: @deus It actually clears the margin overlap. This is the same as giving `body {overflow: hidden;}`. Check it out and see... `:)`

Comment: Dude, the gap disappears because, it clears the overlapped margin. Got it?

Answer (score 3):

Reason are [Adjoining margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) – your `margin-top: 5em` for `#logoBox` gets adjoined with the margin-top of the div.